# What happened to Application.handle in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, migration, delphi-xe, delphi-6

I'm porting some code to Delphi XE and noticed that if I use Application.Handle to get the handle of the program, Delphi throws me an error and refuses to compile, saying:

```
Undeclared identifier: 'Handle'
```

This same behavior happens when I try to call Application.ProcessMessages.  I figure something must have gotten shifted around that wasn't listed in the Unicode Migration guide.

Where did the functions and variables for 'Application' go?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that this unit imports `SvcMgr` after it imports `Forms` and so the `Application` variable in `SvcMgr` takes the one that you want in `Forms` out of scope. Or perhaps the culprit is `WebBroker` or `CtlPanel`.

You can work out which it is by CTRL clicking on the `Application` variable at the point of the first error and you'll land in a unit that isn't `Forms`.

The solution is just to reorder your imports so that `Forms` comes in after the others.

On the other hand, my psychic debugging powers could be broken today!

Comment: Reminds me of `Windows.Bitmap` hiding `Graphics.Bitmap` if you mess up the `uses` order.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Too true. Only it's really `Windows.BITMAP` yelling at you, "Don't use me! I'm the wrong one!". This is one area of the language that I feel is weak. Uses was done much better in Modula-2.

Comment: David, you were pretty much spot on.  The problem wasn't the USES clause, but rather that I had a 'with WebBrowser1 do begin ... Application.handle ... end'.  It was using the 'Application' from the webbrowser object.  THANKS!

Comment: @Daisetsu @CodeInChaos Thanks for letting us know. This is another area of the language which is weak. I have banned the use of `with` in my company!

Comment: Maybe Embarcadero could add a Warning or Hint if a WITH causes ambiguity (to a person, obviously not to the compiler)

Comment: @Gerry That would be a great addition. I could see it being useful in all scoping resolution situations.

Comment: @Gerry: I'd rather just have a "warn on with" option. Unfortunately it would throw so many warnings on the RTL/VCL that it would be difficult to use properly (or maybe that would teach people not to include VCL source in their library path, who knows)

Comment: @moz "include VCL source in their library path" Yak! Do people do that? Why?

Comment: A warning would be best, possibly off by default. If people insist on compiling VCL code, the warning could be suppresed with {$WARN AMBIGOUS_WITH OFF} in each VCL/RTL file.

Comment: @Gerry Why just `with`? Ambiguous scoping occurs with implicit `Self.`, local variables in nested procedures, uses clauses and probably many other situations. Maybe what we really need is namespaces!

Comment: @David Heffernan: if I knew that I would... actually, no I probably wouldn't be any happier, but at least I'd be more informed. I'm currently removing $(DELPHI)\Lib\Debug and other similar things from project library paths in my new job.

Comment: I love ambiguous and overloaded names that are right there in the VCL. And I love it when you hoist yourself on your own petard (WITH statements) even more.  :-)

Comment: With people importing gigantic units like windows willy-nilly, that will only generate heaps of alarms. Note that the scope is never ambiguous, it is always perfectly in the importing order you specified ;-)

Comment: @Marco OK, ambiguous is the wrong word from that perspective. I agree that back-fitting something like this into existing code bases would flood you with messages.